# Sending data through socket without dependency of receiving data

Tags: python, sockets

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        if not self.MessagesQueue.empty():
            self.sendMessage()                         
        response=self.s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
            self.processResponse(response)
        time.sleep(1)
def addMessageToQueue(self,message): #called from main thread
    self.MessagesQueue.put(message)
```

This code is running on a thread, The problem with the code is that recv blocks the thread so I can sendMessage() only if I received 1024 bytes of data, I want to send data whenever I want even in an iteration where 1024 bytes not received completely.

How should I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing send and receive in the same thread if you don't want a dependency?

Comment: Can I use the socket for sending while it is blocked in recv?

Comment: Yes, you can. The two directions are independent channels.

Comment: If that so I don't need to synchronize the socket if i have two threads that one sends and one receives, is that correct?

Comment: Whether you need to synchronize them depends on the application. If your application doesn't need to synchronize, you can do them in different threads.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, it was useful information I missed somehow, you can answer the question so i'll accept it.

Comment: The alternative approach would be to make the socket non-blocking so that send() and recv() never block.  (To keep the thread from spinning you could have it block inside select() or poll(), which can be made to return only when the socket has incoming-data-ready-to-read or outgoing-buffer-space ready-to-write-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the send and receive in different threads if the application doesn't require you to synchronize them. Each direction of a thread is independent, there's no problem with sending in one thread while another thread is blocked in `recv()`.